# Why my alert function is not working when I click on button in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my index.html

```
<body>
    <app></app>
</body>
```

This is my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { App }
})
```

This is my App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img class="logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <hello></hello>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hello from './components/Hello'

export default {
  components: {
    Hello
  }
}
</script>
```

and this is my Hello.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>
        {{ msg }}
    </h1>
    <button v-on:click="showAlert">Click</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {

      msg: 'Hello World!'
    }
  },
  showAlert: () => {
    alert('test')
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the error message from the Chrome console:

> [Vue warn]: v-on:click="showAlert" expects a function value, got undefined (found in component: )

I can see "Hello world!" on my screen and the button but nothing happened when I click on it.

I suppose I will have "test" alert message.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: print your console error messages here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your methods need to be in [your `methods` section](https://vuejs.org/guide/events.html).

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {

      msg: 'Hello World!'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showAlert: () => {
      alert('test')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for help!It works. If I change alert to " this.msg = this.msg.reverse()" and it show "Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined", why I can not access to msg?

Comment: Shouldn't that just be `alert(this.msg.reverse())`?

Comment: Actually, JS's `reverse` appears to be for arrays, not strings.

Comment: What I want is to never hello world on screen when I click button

Comment: @aBloomer What do you mean? `hello world` is in the screen because you have `<h1>{{ msg }}</h1>` in the template.

Comment: I will use this.msg = this.msg.split('').reverse().join()

Comment: I thought it will re-render because I change the msg

Comment: Yes, it will re-render if you change `this.msg`. Check your console and post an example via something like Codepen if it isn't.

Comment: my console just show "TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined"

Comment: Put a copy of that code up on Codepen for us to look at. That implies `this` is not what it should be, which implies something else going on.

Comment: Thanks for help. I figure it out. I can pass 'this' to showAlert o'clock function like v-on:click="showAlert(this)", and get msg from this.msg then change it.

Comment: just dont user arrow function if you want to refer to this

Answer (score 2):

Here is a helpful way I found to add alerts to all your expressions without having to add a method to each Vue component. Adjust the service path to whatever you want.

Create a file called /src/services/utility.js and place in it:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    //alert wrapper for template debugging
    alert(msg) {
      if (msg === undefined) msg = 'Undefined';
      if (msg === '') msg = 'Empty String';
      alert(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

Now in your main.js file import the file and set it as a global mixin

```
import utility from '@/services/utility'
Vue.mixin(utility);
```

And a simple button to test it out

```
<button @click="alert('Meow!')">Make cat speak</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
methods: {
    showAlert: () => {
    alert('test')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>
        {{ msg }}
    </h1>
    <button v-on:click="showAlert">Click</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello World!'
    }
  },
 methods: {
    showAlert: () => {
    alert('test')
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of just `alert('Hello')`, you need to do a `window.alert('Hello')`